# Enviar mensagem de erro para o usuário (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho a seguinte situação: no meu controller `MovementsController`  tenho uma action `Details` que é responsável por realizar uma busca no banco de dados através do `Id` recebido. A dúvida é: caso nenhum dado seja encontrado no banco de dados como faço para direcionar o usuário para uma página de erro contendo o motivo do erro (no caso a propridade `Message` do objeto do tipo `Exception`)? A única coisa parecida que consegui fazer até agora foi lançar um `HttpException` para que o usuário seja direcionado para uma página personalizada `NotFound.cshtml`, conforme configurado no `Web.config`.

Action `Details`:

```
    // GET: Movements/Details
    public ActionResult Details (int? Id)
    {
        try
        {
            return View(_service.GetById(Id.GetValueOrDefault()));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException e)
        {
            if (e is NotFoundException)
                throw new HttpException();
            else
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
```

`Web.config`:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Errors/Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não necessariamente precisa de uma exception para executar o `customErrors`, você pode simplesmente retornar o Status Code que você quer:

```
catch (ApplicationException e) when (e is NotFoundException)
{
     return NotFound();
}
catch (ApplicationException e)
{
     return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Como vai ter um redirecionamento, você precisaria armazenar a mensagem de erro em algum lugar, sugiro utilizar o [`TempData`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#tempdata):

```
catch (ApplicationException e) when (e is NotFoundException)
{
     TempData["ErrorMessage"] = e.Message;
     return NotFound();
}
```

E depois utilizar na `View` do erro:

```
@TempData["ErrorMessage"].ToString()
```

Se não quiser armazenar estes valores, você também poderia redirecionar à action de erro utilizando o `RedirectToAction` passando a mensagem do erro como um parâmetro.

Comment: Entendi.. porém, sempre que o método `NotFound()` é executado o usuário é direcionado para uma página de erro padrão do IIS, mesmo eu tendo definido uma página customizada no `Web.config`. Entretanto, quando eu tento acessar uma action que não existe o servidor me retorna a página de erro customizada.

Comment: Vish, eu acho q vc não vai conseguir usar desta forma então. Você teria que usar o httpErrors ao invés do customErrors

Comment: Adaptei o Web.config para usar o httpErrors também e funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!